# Matching values from rows into column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm matching two worksheets to extract the selected value based on a set of conditions.

My two worksheets & goal worksheet look similar to this:

**True Data**

```
Flavor ID      Size ID      California      Europe       China   
2              4            2               5                
1              3                            4               
3              1            3                            2   
1              2            4                            2
```

**Sheet to Repopulate**

```
Flavor ID          Size ID           Score ID        Location
2                  4                 1               California
1                  3                 1               Europe       
3                  1                 1               China
1                  2                 1               California
```

**Goal**

```
Flavor ID          Size ID           Score ID        Location
2                  4                 2               California
1                  3                 4               Europe       
3                  1                 2               China
1                  2                 4               California
```

So in short, I'm matching on Flavor ID & Size ID to extract the values under the locations from the True Data worksheet to the appropriate cell in the Score ID column in the Sheet to Repopulate sheet.

I initially started to use an index/match combo;

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A1:AK51,
MATCH(1, (TrueData!$A:$A = SheettoPopulate!A2)*(TrueData!$B:$B = SheettoPopulate!B2)*(TrueData!$C$1:$E$1 = SheettoPopulate!D2), 0)
, _____)`

but then realized I wasn't sure how to extract the values *underneath* the locations into one column (the confusion is at the last argument).

Comment: Post the code you've tried & someone will help you tweak it to make it work, but it's unlikely you're going to get someone to write it for you.

Comment: What happened to 3              1            3  California? This started off looking like an unpivot type operation but less sure now.

Comment: @FreeMan edited / added

Comment: @QHarr so the last 3 from the 3 1 3 row would only be brought in if the row from the sheet to populate with ID's 3, 1 was looking for California - but it's looking for China. So only China's value was populated with a 2

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS with INDEX to return the correct column:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C:E,0,MATCH(K2,$C$1:$E$1,0)),A:A,H2,B:B,I2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this on some sample data to populate the `Score ID` column. Put in `B2` and drag down. Note, you'll have to change some ranges depending on the size of your data table, etc. This is just an example with the sample data you provided.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'True Data'!$B$1:$E$5,CELL("col",INDEX('True Data'!$C$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(Goal!$D2,'True Data'!$C$1:$E$1,0))) - 1,FALSE)
```

On the `True Data` tab:

[image: Image1]

And then on my `Goal` tab:

[image: Image2]

I had to use `CELL` to get the reference column with `INDEX/MATCH`, then I used that as the return column in a `VLOOKUP` formula.

EDIT: Here is the formula that works off of the 2 columns:

```
=INDEX('True Data'!$A$1:$E$5,MATCH(1,('True Data'!A:A=Goal!A2)*('True Data'!B:B='True Data'!B2),0),CELL("col",INDEX('True Data'!$C$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(Goal!$D2,'True Data'!$C$1:$E$1,0))))
```

NOTE: That's an array formula.

Comment: Oops, I just realized you're using a combo of `FlavorID` and `Size ID` - let me see if I can alter it...